# Puppeteer typing trigger an error in aws lambda

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, puppeteer

I'm creating a scraping that runs on the AWS Lambda functions, but when I type my query on the site, it triggers an error that I cannot reproduce on my local environment. Does anyone know what can it be?

Code:

```js
query: async (name, birthDate, cpf) => {
    logger.info('QUERY_PARAMS_AP', '', [name, birthDate, cpf]);
    try {
      await page.waitFor(5000);

      await page.type('input[id="formNome"]', name);
      await page.type('input[id="formDataDeNascimento"]', birthDate);
      await page.type('input[id="formCpf"]', cpf);
      ...
```

The error is triggered in the page.type method.

Triggered error below:

```
{ Error: Protocol error (Input.dispatchKeyEvent): Target closed.
       at Promise (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/Connection.js:183:56)
       at new Promise (<anonymous>)
       at CDPSession.send (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/Connection.js:182:12)
       at Keyboard.up (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/Input.js:137:24)
       at Keyboard.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/helper.js:112:23)
       at Keyboard.press (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/Input.js:180:16)
     -- ASYNC --
       at Keyboard.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/helper.js:111:15)
       at Keyboard.type (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/Input.js:162:20)
     -- ASYNC --
       at Keyboard.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/helper.js:111:15)
       at ElementHandle.type (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/JSHandle.js:363:31)
     -- ASYNC --
       at ElementHandle.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/helper.js:111:15)
       at DOMWorld.type (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/DOMWorld.js:422:18)
     -- ASYNC --
       at Frame.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/helper.js:111:15)
       at Page.type (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/Page.js:1103:29)
       at Object.query (/var/task/sources/AP/scraping.js:102:18)
     message: 'Protocol error (Input.dispatchKeyEvent): Target closed.' } }
```

Comment: Solved the issue by changing the lambda location.

Comment: What do you mean changing the lambda location? You should answer the question if you figured it out.